# Simple Python File I/O spell check program

Tags: python-3.x, string, file-io, text-files, spell-checking

For a class I have to create a simple spell checking program that takes two files as inputs, one containing correctly spelled words and one containing a paragraph with a few misspelled words. I thought I had it figured out but I am getting an error I have never seen before. When the program finishes it gives the error:

```
<function check_words at 0x7f99ba6c60d0>
```

I have never seen this nor do I know what it means, any help in getting this program working would be appreciated. Program code is below:

```
import os
def main():
    while True:
        dpath = input("Please enter the path to your dictionary:")
        fpath = input("Please enter the path to the file to spell check:")
        d = os.path.isfile(dpath)
        f = os.path.isfile(fpath)

        if d == True and f == True:
            check_words(dpath, fpath)
            break

    print("The following words were misspelled:")
    print(check_words)

def linecheck(word, dlist):
    if word in dlist:
        return None
    else:
        return word

def check_words(dictionary, file_to_check):
    d = dictionary
    f = file_to_check
    dlist = {}  
    wrong = []  


    with open(d, 'r') as c:
        for line in c:
            (key) = line.strip()
            dlist[key] = ''

    with open(f, 'r') as i:
        for line in i:
            line = line.strip()
            fun = linecheck(line, dlist)
            if fun is not None:
                wrong.append(fun)

    return wrong

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: _call_ the function to execute it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, don't do `print(check_words)`, do `print(check_words())`

Furthermore, change `check_words(dpath, fpath)` to `misspelled_words = check_words(dpath, fpath)`

And change `print(check_words)` to `print(misspelled_words)`

Final code (with a few modifications):

```
import os
def main():
    while True:
        dpath = input("Please enter the path to your dictionary: ")
        fpath = input("Please enter the path to the file to spell check: ")
        d = os.path.isfile(dpath)
        f = os.path.isfile(fpath)

        if d == True and f == True:
            misspelled_words = check_words(dpath, fpath)
            break

    print("\nThe following words were misspelled:\n----------")
    #print(misspelled_words) #comment out this line if you are using the code below

    #optional, if you want a better looking output

    for word in misspelled_words:   # erase these lines if you don't want to use them
        print(word)                 # erase these lines if you don't want to use them

    #------------------------ 


def linecheck(word, dlist):
    if word in dlist:
        return None
    else:
        return word

def check_words(dictionary, file_to_check):
    d = dictionary
    f = file_to_check
    dlist = {}  
    wrong = []  


    with open(d, 'r') as c:
        for line in c:
            (key) = line.strip()
            dlist[key] = ''

    with open(f, 'r') as i:
        for line in i:
            line = line.strip()
            fun = linecheck(line, dlist)
            if fun is not None:
                wrong.append(fun)

    return wrong

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: fixed all the problems I thought I had but ran into a new one. now the program is saying that any word that is capitalized is spelled wrong. I'm pretty new to Python so is there any type of .equalsIgnoreCase function that I could call to have it ignore capitalization?

Comment: Well you can just convert the word to lowercase and then check it. Like so: `word.lower()`

Comment: would I put that in the linecheck function like "if word.lower() in dlist:"   ?

Comment: So, does linecheck() actually check the word to see if its spelled wrong?

Comment: no it just compares the words from that line to the dlist so that is where I would want to put it

Answer (score 3):

It's not an error, it's doing exactly what you are telling it to.

This line:

`print(check_words)`

You are telling it to print a function. The output you are seeing is just Python printing the name of the function and it's address: "printing the function".